# I want to replicate my sub site similar to my primary site in Wordpress Multisite Network

Tags: multisite

I want to setup multi site network for my website for different regions, I have made network and installed two sites but i cant replicate my original site to my new site. I have made a new site using sub directory and it has new wordpress installed. I have backup files of my primary site but I dont know where to upload them as I am unable to find the directory of new site in cpanel.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is the export with the WordPress plugin in your current installation and import in the new site of the Multisite. Makes more sense in context of update of links and media files.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a multi-network rather than a multi-site? Multi-network sites are complicated, you would be better off just assigning people to sites in a multisite and keeping super admin access just for yourself, that way users can only see the sites they're supposed to